# Loggin apt history to syslog

Tags: apt, rsyslog

I have a centralized log management server (graylog) and I want to be able to see the installed/updated/removed packages from a couple of ubuntu serveres there is running.
But is there anyway to redirect the apt history logs to syslog so rsyslog can push them to the graylog server? I know CentOS yum's package manager does this by default but i haven't been able to fina a solution for Ubuntus apt.